# Does IDFA persist across uninstalls?

Tags: ios

I'm using IDFA to identify devices.  If a user uninstalls all of my apps, will the IDFA reset when they next install one of my apps (like with IDFV)?

Comment: The IDFA is the same value across all apps and in Safari on a given device, but the user can reset it at any time.  You should not use the IDFA to identify devices outside of the permitted advertising uses and you should respect the "limit tracking" setting if required by your use.

Comment: Are you talking about `UIDevice identifierForVendor` or `ASIdentifierManager advertisingIdentifier`?